# How to check if zip entry is directory in Go language

Tags: directory, go, zip

I guess some bit in following structure is marking file as directory.
But I can't find reference to that.

http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader

Comment: Hi - it's a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't think the Go package exposes that information...

Comment: @Evan It does, see the answer by Greg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zip package's [`FileHeader`](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader) type, which you linked to, has a [`.FileInfo()`](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/zip/#FileHeader.FileInfo) method which returns an [`os.FileInfo`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileInfo) type, which itself has an `.IsDir()` method.

So chaining that all together, you can tell if the file in the zip archive is a directory with `f.FileInfo().IsDir()`.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Open a zip archive for reading.
    r, err := zip.OpenReader("example.zip")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer r.Close()

    // Iterate through the files in the archive,
    // indicating if it is a directory.
    for _, f := range r.File {
        fmt.Printf("%s is directory? - %v\n", f.Name, f.FileInfo().IsDir())
    }
}
```